# (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) missing FROM-clause entry for table "t"

Tags: postgresql, insert

I got an error when trying to insert into table s from t using postgres,

```
INSERT INTO s (name, site_square_footage)
SELECT name, site_square_footage
FROM temp_sites AS t
ON CONFLICT (name)
    DO UPDATE SET 
        site_square_footage = t.site_sqaure_footage
```

please help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out the answer by refer to the postgres documentation, the syntax is a bit odd.

```
INSERT INTO s (name, site_square_footage)
SELECT name, site_square_footage
FROM temp_sites AS t
ON CONFLICT (name)
    DO UPDATE SET 
        site_square_footage = excluded.site_sqaure_footage
```